Django Migration Error: admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency users.0001_initial
I'm building a Django application with a custom user model, and I'm getting a migration error. I've already created my initial migrations but when trying to apply them, I get a dependency error.
Error Message
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency users.0001_initial on database 'default'.
here is my My Settings Configuration (settings/base.py):
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_extensions',
    'simple_history',
    'phonenumber_field',
]

LOCAL_APPS = [
     'apps.users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'apps.courses.apps.CoursesConfig',
    'apps.calendar_app.apps.CalendarAppConfig',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

What I've tried:
Running python manage.py makemigrations users
Running python manage.py migrate
Both commands result in the same error. How can I fix this without deleting my database?

can you explain the scenario before this error? e.g. you change the users.0001_initial or change AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings after some migrations.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project
